# How can I level water?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]

It may be my inner OCD, but situations like this annoy me to no end. Sometimes, a patch of water is "ruined" for no apparent rational reason and all attempts to restore it to normality are met with failure.

My latest attempt was building dirt where the currents were, then removing it. The result is pictured. :/

Is there something I can do about it, or is it just a glitch?

Comment: +1 for OCD. I can very much appreciate. I used to move my whole city one square to the left in Sim City.

Comment: Only here could a question like this: 1) Be asked in the first place, but 2) Get such excellent, detailed answers.

Comment: This question is not relevant for Minecraft 1.5. Since 1.5, water source blocks replicate if there's a solid block **or a water source block** underneath.

Comment: @OrcJMR You're right. Here's a bounty if you want to submit an updated answer. :)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie This does not happen at all anymore in the latest versions: http://youtu.be/1BhR2D3KZAQ

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Does this question even make sense now? I can just delete it if this problem doesn't happen anymore.

Comment: @badp Yes, the question now makes sense only in relation to older versions. I suggest finding out which exactly, editing it in, and leaving it here.

Comment: @badp It can still happen, it just doesn't happen as easily as it used to. It will be rarer, but we will still get incoming searches on this.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie How to reproduce it?

Comment: @3ventic I actually can't think of a way. Water current turns into water source when there are two water sources on its sides and a solid block or a water source underneath. It is impossible to reproduce in the middle of body of water.

Comment: @orc people using older, "unsupported" versions of minecraft are typically on their own. We don't keep questions about boosters around for people who stopped updating two years ago :-)

Comment: @badp I managed to create one in 1.6.2. 1) Find a body of water. 2) Dig a hole in the bottom. Place a block over the hole (without filling it in). 3) Build upward from that block to the surface. 4) Go back down and destroy the tower from the bottom up. A column of downward current will be formed. This may happen in the normal course of play during odd construction projects. Though, again, rarely, and now it's easily fixed with the answer I just awarded the bounty to.

Answer (score 65):

Place dirt right underneath the crazy currents and it should sort itself out automatically.

If it doesn't, add a source block to the place all the water flows to.

Comment: Awesome! [This got the job done in under a minute.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iWA3zemvls)

Answer (score 25):

The problem is that there are missing source blocks (aka spring blocks) from the top level of the lake.

Since water source blocks only replicate if there is a empty block that is adjacent to two source blocks and has a normal block underneath it (no glass, reeds, mob spawners or anything like that.) it can't refill the top layer of a deep lake.  One way to fix it is to make it a shallow lake by placing dirt under it, but this can lead to underwater currents when the block is removed.

The cleanest way to fix it is to re-fill that missing source block with a bucket.  But you say there is no solid block to pour the bucket out on to?  Then place a block above it!.

[image: broken water]
[image: tetris block!]

And dive under it, look up and dump a bucket of water.
[image: underwater view]
No underwater currents created!

Of course,  in my example pictures, it's only 2 blocks deep, so a dirt block on the bottom of the lake would have worked just as well.

Comment: Great solution for if you're trying to level deep water, +1!

Comment: oh god... _underwater_ currents?

Comment: Well, compare swimming up a waterfall to swimming upwards in a lake.  That's the difference.

Comment: I am astounded by the existence of the instructions: "Dive under it, look up and dump a bucket of water." Maybe we should be encouraging everyone to file suggestions to the devs to fix it instead, despite being an abnormal suggestion for Arqade.

Comment: @NiteCyper It was explicitly broken by devs, since otherwise you could grief by towering up high, and building a large 'L' of source blocks.  Without the restriction on when source blocks propagate, it would create a giant cube of source blocks, taking forever to remove.

Answer (score 24):

There's a new solution to this that requires Creative mode in multiplayer, and even works underwater.

First, go into creative mode fill the affected area with ice blocks. You can enable Creative in multiplayer by typing `/gamemode <username> creative` in chat.
[image]

Next, go back into Survival mode (`/gamemode <username> survival`) and smash them with a pickaxe.
[image]

Ta-da! The smashed ice blocks are now water source.
[image]

Comment: +1 I think this solves both surface and underwater currents.

Answer (score 11):

In version 1.5 (and beyond), this issue of non-source blocks mussing up your lakes can only  occur if you lake has missing source blocks (flowing water) all the way to the bottom of the lake. this can drown your animals, so there is more reason than ever to repair it.

To fix it, place blocks on the bottom of the lake under any flowing water. This will recreate and update all the rest of the water all the way to the surface.  if this doesn't fix everything, place another layer. Large areas of flowing water (from supercharged creeper blasts or improperly made artificial lakes) may require placing a bucket of water or two on the blocks you have placed.

When it is fixed, you may remove all the blocks you have placed.

Answer (score 5):

I've had trouble with this as well. My solution was to wall off my pool into 4-by-4 (1 deep) cells and fill those with water using the "endless well" technique of emptying a water bucket into two opposite corners.

Once you've filled every cell, you can start breaking down the walls between the cells one block at a time. Sometimes the same effect that makes the endless well work will fill the removed block fully. Sometimes it won't. If it doesn't, empty a bucket directly onto the space.

For pools more than one block deep, completely fill the bottom layer and then build the cell network for the next higher level "suspended" over your filled layer and continue the process.

Repeat *ad infinitum*. Obviously this takes a lot of time and effort.

Of course in your case, since you just have one "little" problem area (compared to the total area of your pool), try walling off just that area, removing the water, and trying my method above, destroying the outer walls last.

The key is to remember that water in a bucket is a block just like everything else.

Comment: I guess my inner OCD will have to put up with cementification, then :D

Comment: I had to fix some situations like this in my dock and I found it easiest usually to extend a 1-block "bridge" out to the offending spot.  You can then use the edge of the bridge blocks as an anchor point to drop the water block and fill the gap.  Then mine out the bridge, filling the water back in as you go.

Answer (score 5):

I've created a mod that fixes this problem. [It's available here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1197409-water-spring-propagation-fix/).

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a rectangular dirt perimeter around "troubled waters", with 2 wide, 2 deep cross-section, having 2 cubes above water level and 2 below.
2. Working from outside corner, strip away upper outside edge, allowing water to advance 1 square towards centre.
    The revealed underwater cube (x-section is now "L" shaped") prevents creation of a downwards flow and the one above water level prevents flooding of the central area. This revealed strip of underwater cubes can now be safely removed and reclaimed.
3. Repeat this 2x2 construction inside previous perimeter, successively shrinking it towards the centre each time.

Comment: This is redundant since water mechanics changed.

Answer (score 2):

Under the block that is "oddly" flowing, place a block under it it works for me.

Comment: Hello necromancer! Could you refrain from answering questions that have already been answered? It appears that you have enough reputation to add a comment to the question or one of the answers.

Comment: @Jeffrey Actually, it takes 50 reputation to post a comment.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought it was 15.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion: if you have ice blocks, place them where the crazy currents are and break them. If you have no ice, then you will need a bucket of water, an infinite water source and some scaffolding. Like with the ice, place your scaffolding over all the currents, except one. Empty your bucket there. Refill the bucket using your infinite water source. Then break another scaffold and empty your bucket there. Rinse and repeat.