# How can I make Left 4 Dead 2 stop giving me a female avatar in online Campaign play?

Tags: left-4-dead-2

Playing on XBox Live. Keep dying. Lousy teammates won't revive me. But that's not even the problem...

I KEEP GETTING SPAWNED AS A GIRL!

It's starting to give me a complex. Please, make it stop...

Comment: For a while, my steam user name was "I always random Zoey". I've been there, pal!

Comment: Am I the only one who enjoys when this happens?

Comment: I've heard but can't confirm that it will attempt to use the character you've played most - so if you're forced into Zoe/Rochelle often, it becomes a self-fulfilling prophecy. You can see who you play as on your steam stats page. You can improve the numbers by playing single player/starting your own game so you can pick the appropriate char.

Comment: 12 years later and I revisited L4D2 on Steam. Have you stopped caring yet? :D

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you are in the lobby menu, you can choose the character you want; just pick one other than Rochelle (or Zoey if you're doing a map with L4D1 characters).  If your other three teammates have already selected the other male characters, you are SOL.

[image]

(Picture ripped off some [YouTube L4D2 lobby video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoTqs2NIRxo))

Better yet, stop caring.

Comment: Note that in Versus, you can only choose if you're on the Survivor side first.  If you're on the Infected side first, you'll get randomly assigned a character.

Comment: I upvoted this for "stop caring" more than for the description of the choose character option.

Comment: "Stop caring" should apply to [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10318/how-can-i-level-water) question.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just get an addon that replaces Zoey and Rochelle with boys. In my squad I like playing as a girl, but Coach was the only guy left that people hadn't taken so they could play their preferred character. I just subscribed to an addon making Coach a girl and shared it with my friends, so they could see it too.

Literally nobody cares who you play as tho... just play well.