# How can I remove water currents?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built a dock at water level, then I wanted to get rid of it. So I started breaking the blocks but water currents formed so that there is water moving inwards from either side of where the dock once was, towards the center, where the water is still. The water sinks towards the center, and I've tried placing a layer of dirt one block beneath water level, but the water is still moving. Please help me fix this!

Comment: place water on the dirt

Comment: Try looking here for suggestions: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10318/how-can-i-level-water

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will start this answer with a question. Is your flowing water only 1 block deep?

---

**Yes**

Good in this case you can use either 2 ways.

The first one is to fill the area with an easy to remove block (for example dirt) also fill the water blocks that are still source blocks. Then dig the first corner block away. Wait for the source blocks to fill the other block and dig the next block away.

**Sidenote** : For flowing water to create a source block you need to have 2 or more water flows coming from the sides and the water cant flow farther then 1 block. An example is found below.

```
X X X X X
D D D X X
D D D D D
D D D D D
D D D D D
```

X being water and D being Dirt. 
Removing the top-middle dirt block results in 2 water blocks (X's) to flow in the empty space and the water cant flow further then 1 block because of the other dirt blocks, thus creating a source block.

Another example

```
X X X X X
X X D X X
D D D D D
D D D D D
D D D D D
```

Removing the top middle D again results in 3 source blocks to flow into the empty space and thus creating a source block.

Another example

```
X X X X X
D D D D D
D D D D D
D D D D D
D D D D D
```

Removing the top-middle D block here results into only 1 source block to flow into the empty space thus creating flowing water.

This methode takes a long time so the fastest way is create some buckets and collect some water. Then dig a row of dirt away and replace the flowing water with water from your buckets. (You can place the water against the dirt blocks your standing on.)

---

**No**

If its more than 1 block deep you need to wonder if its worth spending the time seeing as there is no quick way to solve this. What i would do is to empty the area with the flowing water (yes just empty it till the bottom and wall off with dirt. Now fill the bottom layer with water. Next place a layer of dirt above the water (like shown below).

```
D D D D D
D D D D D
D D D D D
D D D D D
D D D D D
```

Now dig an entire row of dirt away and replace the air space with a bucket.(like shown below).

```
X X X X X
D D D D D
D D D D D
D D D D D
D D D D D
```

Repeat until you have filled the entire area with water blocks.

Now for removing the wall you have build, remove the top layer of the wall and place water on top of there. Once you have done that just repeat this layer after layer until you have reached a bottom. (you might want to take some scubba gear with you.(sugarcanes, metal bars, signs etc.)).

I think this has covered the most ways of getting rid of the flowing water. However neither of these ways can be considered fast so if anyone knows a faster way feel free to add it to my answer.

Anyway i hope this helped.

Cheers, Marco

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful :) it didn't take too long either

Comment: @Minecraft Since somve version, 1.4 or 1.5, water source blocks form not only above solid blocks, but also above other water source blocks. Do you play an older version?

Comment: @OrcJMR no but it has been some time since i went water levelling so the physics might be a bit off. The approach stays the same however.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Build out the land all the way out until all of the water that is "broken" ends.  Then slowly, one layer at a time, dig back toward where you want the shore to start.  If you do it slow enough, the water should run into the block space as you remove it and flatten.

Option 2: Find an area with water, get a bucket of water and poor the water against the side of the land blocks.  The water that is running is being treated like a non-source water block.  Pouring a bucket of water onto the block in question will turn it into a soure block.  If you've already placed blocks beneath the water (1 block below) as you say you have, you should be able to apply the buckets to those blocks as well and fix the water above it.

Answer (score 0):

Place a block of dirt (or other block) on the water block.

After removing the block of dirt the water will no longer be there.

**OR** (only in creative mode)

Place a sponge underwater.